# Why can't I enable ingress in minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I am trying to enable ingress in minkube. When I run `minikube addons enable ingress` it hangs for a while then I get the following error message:

```
❌  Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: run callbacks: running callbacks: [sudo KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minikube/kubeconfig /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.19.15/kubectl apply -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-deploy.yaml: Process exited with status 1
stdout:
namespace/ingress-nginx unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx unchanged
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller unchanged
configmap/tcp-services unchanged
configmap/udp-services unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission unchanged

stderr:
error: error validating "/etc/kubernetes/addons/ingress-deploy.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "ipFamilies" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec, ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "ipFamilyPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
 waiting for app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx pods: timed out waiting for the condition]

╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│    Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                             │
│    - /tmp/minikube_addons_2c0e0cafd16ea0f95ac51773aeef036b316005b6_0.log                  │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

This the the minikube start command I used:
`minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.19.15 --vm-driver=docker`

I have tried reinstalling minikube. It was working fine last week when I ran the same command.

If more specific information is needed please let me know and I will edit the question. Does anyone know how I could go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't have to enable ingress addon every time you start minikube, it is just one time activity. Are you trying to enable it every time?

Comment: No, I am setting it up an environment from scratch. I ran `minikube delete` beforehand.

Answer (score 10):

Bit late, but I hope someone find this useful, this happens becouse minikube could not pull the image(ingress-nginx-controller) in time, the way to know is:

```
kubectl get pod -n ingress-nginx
```

If the ingress-nginx-controller-xxxx (xxxx is the identifier of the pod) has a status of ImagePullBackOff or something like that, you are on this scenario.

To fix you will need to first describe you pod:

```
kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller-xxxxx -n ingress-nginx
```

Look under containers/controller/images and copy its value(don't need to copyp the @sha256:... if it contains it). You must to manually pull it, but before probably delete the related deployment as well:

```
kubectl delete deployment ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
```

And then pull the image from the vm itself, in my case looks like this:

```
minikube ssh docker pull k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.2.1
```

Wait for it and then try to "addons enable ingress" again and see if it works, it did it for me.

Comment: Downloading the images for this addon is extremely slow, so I've downloaded them locally (`docker pull`) and then load the images into minikube before trying to enable the addon, e.g. `minikube image load registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.8.1`. Saves having to download it again just to rebuild minikube

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading to minikube v1.23.2 fixed the issue.

Comment: I am using a Ubuntu 20.04 VM.  Originally I use minikube v1.28.0, and run into this issue.  Doing a fresh install for v1.23.2 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Which operating system are you using?

- The ingress, and ingress-dns addons are currently only supported on Linux. https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/
- You still can run minikube with vmware

```sh
# If you are using Mac:
brew install docker-machine-driver-vmware
# Start a cluster using the vmware driver:
minikube start --driver=vmware
# To make vmware the default driver:
minikube config set driver vmware
```

Comment: Thanks but I am on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to minikube v1.26.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: I have this problem with 1.26.0. I think it's not the version, but the act of upgrading does something.

Comment: I did a fresh install of minikube v1.26.0.  Didn't fix the problem.  Doing the same for v1.23.2 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The error in my case is:

> X Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: run callbacks: running callbacks: [NewSession: new client: new client: Error creating new native config from ssh using: docker, &{[] [C:\Users<user>.minikube\machines\minikube\id_rsa]}: open C:\Users<user>.minikube\machines\minikube\id_rsa: **Access is denied.** waiting for app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx pods: timed out waiting for the condition]

Simple fix is to run PowerShell using Administrator (I'm on Windows).
I am using v1.26.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.
I was trying to enable it with running this command
`minikube addons enable ingress`
while minikube was in stopped state.

I started minukube, then ran the command it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
minikube delete --all --purge


minikube addons enable ingress
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the problem that it says The 'ingress' addon is enabled but wasn't creating the namespace ingress-nginx and its pods. This answer worked for me, I'm using macOS with m1.