# Error while minikube addons enable ingress on windows

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I'm trying to enable minikube ingress addons using the command -
minikube addons enable ingress

But I'm getting the error as -

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5uDA.png)

When I start the minikube I get the warning as - "This container is having trouble accessing https://registry.k8s.io"

```
C:\Users\pratik> minikube start
W0328 12:38:06.983265   18528 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\pratik\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
* minikube v1.32.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19045.4170 Build 19045.4170
* Automatically selected the docker driver
* Using Docker Desktop driver with root privileges
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Pulling base image ...
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) ...
! This container is having trouble accessing https://registry.k8s.io
* To pull new external images, you may need to configure a proxy: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/proxy/
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.28.3 on Docker 24.0.7 ...
  - Generating certificates and keys ...
  - Booting up control plane ...
  - Configuring RBAC rules ...
* Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
  - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

and I suspect that this is the cause why I'm unable to pull the ingress-nginx controller image from registry.

How can we fix this and also enable the ingress addons.?

Following are few things things that I have tried with did not work.

- I have tried running powershell in administrator mode and executing the command, which did not work.
- I tried pulling the images manually and then trying to run the

  ```
  minikube addons enable ingress
  ```
- ```
  minikube delete
  ```

  ```
  minikube start
  ```

  ```
  minikube addons enable ingress
  ```
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/18021#issuecomment-1953589210
- [Why can't I enable ingress in minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068633/why-cant-i-enable-ingress-in-minikube/74582151#74582151?newreg=100d4a2c3c3d49ceb99ffbee1950cec9)
- reinstalled minikube